# windows環境でcondaにpytorchが入りません

Tags: python, 機械学習, windows-10, anaconda, pytorch

anaconda環境にpytorchをインストールしようとしているのですが、何度試してもimportエラーが出てしまいます。
anacondaで仮想環境を作り、焼ているのですが、下記のような結果になってしまいます

```
(nn) C:\Users\USER>conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


(nn) C:\Users\USER>python -c "import torch; print( torch.__version__ )"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\nn\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\nn\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

(nn) C:\Users\USER>
```

pytorchのページからバージョン指定してインストールする方法も試したのですが、結果は変わりませんでした。

なにか解決方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

環境
windows10
CUDA10.1
cuDNN v7.6.5
NVIDIA2019.3
Intel(R) Core(TM)i7-8750H CPU @2.20GHz 2.21GHz 16.0GB
NVIDIAもインストールしているのでGPUかなと思います

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/278682

Answer (score 1):

以下のコマンドでインストールしてみてください。

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

---

こちらの環境でも同様の現象が発生しました。

```
>python -c "import torch; print( torch.__version__ )"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

StackOverflowで [同様の質問と回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488902/cannot-import-pytorch-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) を見つけました。
「John」さんの回答のとおりにcpu-onlyパッケージをインストールしたところ問題が解消しました。

> This is most probably because you are using a CUDA variant of PyTorch on a system that doesn’t have GPU driver installed. That is to say, if you don’t have a Nvidia GPU card, please install the cpu-only package according to the commands on https://pytorch.org.

GPUドライバーがインストールされていないシステムではcpu-onlyパッケージをインストールする必要があるようです。
私はGPUについて知識がありませんので、残念ながら詳しいことは説明ができません。

```
(base) C:\Users\XXXX>C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import torch; print( torch.__version__ )"
1.5.1
```

Comment: 補足するとPyTorchのページに表示されている`Get Started`のボタンをクリックすると飛ぶこちら[Start Locally | PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)のページで自分の環境に合わせてボタンを選択すると`Run this Command:`の欄にインストール用のコマンドが表示されるので、それを実行すれば良い訳です。それを見ると質問者さんはWindowsの環境でMac用のコマンドを実行したのでしょう。

Comment: cpuonlyのコマンドで入力したらエラー表示なくなりました。ありがとうございました。